# Changes to Oracle forms 12c formsweb.cfg pageTitle parameter do not work - pageTitle remains unchanged

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am moving a forms 10g application to forms 12c 12.1.2.3.  The application uses several config sections in formsweb.cfg that need to have different Page Titles displayed - that should be able to be accomplished by setting the pageTitle parameter in the config sections for each configuration like this:

```
[HotToolRoom]
pageTitle=Hot Tool Room Inventory - Config [HotToolRoom]
lookAndFeel=ORACLE
form=hotinv.fmx
WebUtilArchive=frmwebutil.jar,jacob.jar
WebUtilLogging=on
WebUtilLoggingDetail=normal
WebUtilErrorMode=Alert
WebUtilDispatchMonitorInterval=5
WebUtilTrustInternal=true
WebUtilMaxTransferSize=16384
baseHTML=webutilbase.htm
baseHTMLjpi=webutiljpi.htm
archive=frmall.jar,bfd_gifs.jar
otherparams=rp2rs=rep_wls_reports_aa dtr=C01 rto=Y
envFile=C:\app\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\aa\config\fmwconfig\servers\WLS_FORMS\applications\formsapp_12.2.1\config\htr.env
workingDirectory=C:\app\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\aa\srcfiles\htr
webFormsTitle=Hot Tool Room Inventory Config [HotToolRoom]
WIDTH=1300
HEIGHT=900
```

This does not work.

The default value of "**Oracle Fusion Middleware Forms Services**" is always displayed no matter what pageTitle is set to in formsweb.cfg.

This is true even when it is changed in the [default] config at the start of formsweb.cfg.
I can't find any other files where pageTitle is set other than formsweb.cfg (there are two locations for formseb.cfg:

One in the Adminserver directory:
C:\app\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\aa\config\fmwconfig\servers\AdminServer\applications\formsapp_12.2.1\config\formsweb.cfg

And the one actually used in the formsapp_12.2.1\config directory:
C:\app\product\fmw\user_projects\domains\aa\config\fmwconfig\servers\WLS_FORMS\applications\formsapp_12.2.1\config\formsweb.cfg

Changing the pageTitle value in both formsweb.cfg files has no affect.

I have tried to figure out everywhere that pageTitle exists and it looks like it is used in the following files:  base.htm. basejpi.htm, webutilbase.htm, webutiljpi.htm - %pageTitle%

I replaced the %pageTitle% reference in each of those files with the respective filename to see which of those files were used, but it still comes back with the default value instead of the literal I used in each of the files.

Has anyone experienced this issue?  If so, what do I have to do to change the pageTitle value?

Any insight on how this works would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, This is what is called a brain-fart - I was looking in the wrong place for the pageTitle - I was looking at the servlet window for any title changes, but the location where the pageTitle shows is in the IE 11 browser tab label, NOT the forms application window.

Oh well, I blew a lot of time looking for something that was right under my nose, but it wasn't a total loss - I know a heck of a lot more about forms configuration than I did before.

Sorry for the unnecessary diversion!